# How to send sms using php script from ftp server

Tags: php, sms

I'm trying to send a sms using php from my ftp server in the background. I want to send a sms whenever I query data from one of my folders. I send GPS coor. to my ftp server in the form of a txt file and use php script to query that data and display it using google maps. I want to send the sms whenever it pulls the lonlat. I know of the mail() in php but wondering how to implement it. I am new to php and have been assisting someone else on this but we have reached a deadend. We're are trying to do this for free.

Comment: you want to send an SMS to *where*?

Comment: basically to my friends number it would only be one number. Part of a project so we just need to be able to do it maybe less than 20 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an SMS by sending an email to the phonenumber@the provider's email address. For example, if the user you wanted to text was a verizon customer and their phone number was 800-555-1234 you would send an email to 8005551234@vtext.com and they would get the text message.

[This web page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27051/use-email-to-send-text-messages-sms-to-mobile-phones-for-free/) provides a nice list of the providers and what email address to use for them.

Comment: This is assuming everywhere in the world works like US carriers.

Comment: This is what I planned on doing

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to do this is to create an account with an SMS gateway and send messages through their api.  You can send SMS messages via email addresses for most providers, but you have to either know the cell phone carrier OR try emailing all of them.  It's a bit of a pain to maintain the email list, as well.

Answer (score 0):

In 99% of the time, the carriers will charge $ for sending SMS's through their gateway. On top of it, you would need a way to interface the gateway that will route/transport the messages for you.

A quick google search for the terms: cheap sms gateway php
- Rendered too many links, but one of them points to an article review of a  free(aka AD supported gateway) that I have never heard of, that you may want to try.

By using their API, you will be able to interact with their service, a full length guide is there for your perusal:

The Guide:
http://www.zeepmobile.com/developers/getting_started/register_your_app

How to send a message through their API:
http://www.zeepmobile.com/developers/getting_started/send_a_message

Answer (score 0):

you can send sms in php.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGFhy0APrLw
live video and also you can get link for download supported software