# How to send SMS using c# application?

Tags: sms

I want to send SMS using any .NET application.
So, How can i send SMS without using third party tools or any gateways???

Comment: The easiest way is by using the corresponding email address for the phone, but support isn't guaranteed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10441262/453277

Answer (score 1):

You can connect directly to some mobile phones using SDKs and send SMS with GSM Modem style commands (AT commands) if it supports it. Old Nokia's used to be fairly simple to do this with.

The email address trick only works for US networks that still charge recipients for SMS which is why they're happy for you to email to the mobile number. It does mean that you have to know the network the handset is on, which you don't need to know when using SMS Gateways.

Have a look at the FrontlineSMS project as well which is an excellent tool that doesn't require using gateways : http://www.frontlinesms.com